# Unable to test my react program, yarn start and test don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-native-web

So I have JUST started learning React Native to try and learn app development. So I started with a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=469&v=_CBYbEGvxYY).

Everything was going fine until I tried running the command `yarn start` in the terminal to start the server and program and I got the following error message:

> error Command "start" not found.

I also tried `yarn test` but got a similar error:

> error Command "test" not found.

I started doing research on why this would happen but I haven't found a solution yet. As you can see from the image my `package.json` has the `start` and `test` commands in it

[image: https://imgur.com/blevpLS]

I've checked for *yarn* with `yarn --version` and it gives me 1.17.3 so I know it exists. I also have node installed.

I should be able to start the app with the `yarn start` command as he does it in the tutorial but it won't find the command.

Comment: Which directory does `package.json` live in?

Comment: Looks like your package.json is a directory deeper. Try `cd react-tut` then `yarn start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run the `yarn test` inside the parent folder of where the package.json is located. Try to cd into the `react-tut/` folder using `cd react-tut` and then run `yarn test`. This should execute the test script that you have in the package.json file, as expected.